# Bootstrap Form-Group with Dropdown Problem

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap

[Screen Shot Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvPpp.png)With below code, an unwanted button is coming with default dropdownlist. please help me to remove this button.

```cs
 <div class="row form-group">
                        <div class="col col-md-3"><label>Nationality</label></div>
                        <div class="col-12 col-md-9">
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.DESelectedNationality, Model.Nationalities, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

i expect dropdownlist with out button, but the actual result is dropdownlist with button. Screenshot attached.